# Converting a .log file into CSV format

Tags: csv, ip, logging, trace, traceroute

I am performing a number of trace routes to different IP's throughout the course of 1 week. Ive got a script that performs a set of trace routes and writes and appends them to the same .log file.

This file is obviously now quite large as I'm performing trace route 3 times a day on 6 targets for a week. Im trying to write a simple program that will convert my log files into CSV format for analysis in Excel.

Before each trace route runs it prints ''--- START ---'' and finishes with ''--- END ---''. See the following example:

```
--- START ---
Mon Mar 12 22:45:05 GMT 2012
traceroute to xxxxxxxx (xxxxxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  xxxxxxx (xxxxxxx)  1.085 ms  1.662 ms  2.244 ms
2  xxxxxx (xxxxxx)  0.792 ms  0.782 ms  0.772 ms
3  xxxxxx (xxxxxx)  8.545 ms  9.170 ms  9.644 ms
4  etc
5  etc
--- END ---
--- START ---
Mon Mar 12 22:45:05 GMT 2012
traceroute to xxxxxx (xxxxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  xxxxxxx (xxxxxxx)  0.925 ms  1.318 ms  1.954 ms
2  xxxxx (xxxxxx)  0.345 ms  0.438 ms  0.496 ms
3  xxxxxxx (xxxxxx)  0.830 ms  2.553 ms  0.809 ms
4 etc
5 etc
--- END ---
```

I was going to use the START and END to delimit and separate each trace route from one another. I also need to take the total number of jumps that each trace routes makes, that being the last number on the line before ''--- END ---".

If anyone could help me out it would be great. I need something that will run through each trace route, separating them. And then showing the number of hops each trace route makes... Im currently using MATLAB.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your problem is using [regex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html). Just find those start and end tags and for each match make the necessary processing :)